# MySQL keyword search query to match items with ALL keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, indexing, keyword

I have a table structure which is basically:

```
Items
ID: INT(10)
Title: CHAR(255)

ItemsWords
ID: INT(10)
ItemID: INT(10)
Word: CHAR(50)
```

For each 'Item' record, there are multiple records in the 'ItemsWords' table.

I can find all items using this which contain a single word like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items i, ItemsWords w WHERE w.ItemID=i.ID AND w.Word='WORD_TO_FIND'
```

I can find all items using this which contain any of a number of words like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Items i, ItemsWords w 
WHERE w.ItemID=i.ID 
AND (w.Word='WORD_TO_FIND' OR w.Word='ANOTHER_WORD_TO_FIND')
```

But I also want to be able to use the same table structure to find only the 'Items' which contain ALL of any number of search words.

I know I could use FullText by the `Items` table has over 100,000 records and the `ItemWords` table many time more than that, so have set up the structure this way to make these searches very quick and with minimum server impact. The one word or ANY word searches above are indeed super speedy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Items.id, Items.Title
from Items
   inner join ItemsWords   
   on Items.ID = ItemsWords.ItemID
where ItemsWords.Word in ('WORD_TO_FIND','ANOTHER_WORD_TO_FIND') 
group by Items.id, Items.Title
having count(distinct ItemsWords.id) =2
```

The number in the final line is the number of words in the list of words you are searching for (ie: 2 in this instance.

Note how the tables are joined using the `inner join` syntax, rather than a `where` clause

Comment: Thank you. Works brilliantly and fast too. Can I ask why you used an inner join as opposed to a left or right join?

Comment: An inner join matches where there is an element in both tables - which is what you are interested in. Left or right (outer) joins match even if there is no match in the joined table.